# Angular Mat DatePicker is broken

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I am facing issue in rendering mat date picker. however it works fine when i reload the page. It only happens when i navigate from one tab to another.

```
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" id="date" required [(ngModel)]="d.date"   name="date">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field><br />
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you paste the error as a text?

Comment: There is no error in console or DEV tool at all.

Comment: Okay then if possible provide stackblitz demo'

Comment: No luck unable to replicate in stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself. In my case, I had a component with ViewEncapsulation.None loaded beforehand with css that broke the datepicker.

Comment: Hi ant_avd. Please show the code of how you solved your problem, or if you didn't solve it, move this answer to a comment. Thanks.